# In ROS Kinetic, commands such as catkin_make give an error. (Python-catkin-pkg dependency broken)

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error content:

```
$ catkin_make
The program 'catkin_make' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install catkin

$ sudo apt install catkin
[sudo] password for developer: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled ROS, but I get the same error.

The same problem occurred in the following three environments.

1. Ubuntu 16.04 installed on desktop PC
2. Ubuntu 16.04 installed on a laptop PC
3. Ubuntu 16.04 installed on Windows 10 VMware

Any advice would be much appreciated.

---

Edit: Below is the installation guide.

http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

It will be an already installed message.

However, catkin_make will not be installed.

```
$ catkin_make
The program 'catkin_make' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install catkin

$ sudo apt install ros-kinetic-catkin
[sudo] password for developer: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-kinetic-catkin is already the newest version (0.7.14-0xenial-20180809-132632-0800).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-kinetic-desktop-full is already the newest version (1.3.2-0xenial-20190320-232543-0800).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322562/in-ros-kinetic,-commands-such-as-catkin_make-give-an-error.-(python-catkin-pkg-dependency-broken)/) by [hiroshi_i_nakamura](https://answers.ros.org/users/40899/hiroshi_i_nakamura/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-06**:\

> ```
> $ sudo apt install catkin
> ```

Ubuntu is suggesting that because of the existence of [upstream packages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).

If you just want to install the "regular ROS packages", you'll want to install `ros-kinetic-catkin`, not `catkin`.

Can you tell us which installation guide / tutorial you've followed?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-09**:\

> ```
> $ catkin_make
> ```

```
The program 'catkin_make' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install catkin
```

just making sure: did you do a `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` before trying to run `catkin_make`?

That is needed as by default `catkin_make` will not be on the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your help.
When run after source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash, catkin_make worked correctly.

---

Originally posted by [hiroshi_i_nakamura](https://answers.ros.org/users/40899/hiroshi_i_nakamura/) with karma: 16 on 2019-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0